# Error con las rutas de los fichero en PHP al hacer require()

Tags: php

estoy trabajando con PHP y me ha surgido un problema que he estado buscando y no he podido solucionar. El problema viene cuando en una clase intento requerir otra clase de esta forma:

```
require 'DAO/usuario.php';
```

Pero cuando llega a estas líneas da error:

```
require '../../compra.php'
```

El error es el siguiente:

```
require (../../compra.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Pero la ruta existe, y está. Alguien sabe porque da este error con esa ruta y sabe como solucionarlo. Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás usando una ruta relativa y, dependiendo de la cadena de `requires` e `includes` que hayas definido, lo que está dos directorios por encima de `DAO/usuario.php` no está dos directorios por encima del script inicial.

Digamos que lo tienes así

```
- index.php 
  - otro directorio
    - otro_script.php
      - DAO
        - usuario.php
```

Se entendería que `compra.php` está en el mismo directorio que `index.php`, pero resulta que `usuario.php` se está ejecutando en tiempo de compilación junto con `index.php`, por lo que estás llamando un archivo dos directorios por encima de `index.php` y eso claramente no existe.

Lo que siempre recomiendo es mantener un solo punto de entrada a la aplicación (index.php) en donde se defina una constante que fije el directorio raíz:

index.php

```
<?php

define('HOMEDIR',__DIR__);

require(HOMEDIR.'/OtroDirectorio/DAO/usuario.php');
```

Y en usuario.php

```
<?php

require(HOMEDIR.'/compra.php');
```

Y la verdadera buena práctica acá, es usar [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) y [autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), para que el namespace de cada clase defina determinísticamente su ubicación en el árbol de archivos, pero a veces no es necesario complicarse tanto si estás experimentando o haciendo una prueba de concepto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho. Espero que a otra gente con el mismo problema le ayude tu respuesta.